# Strongswan remote_ts as 0.0.0.0/0, now I can't access my vps

Tags: vpn, vps, ipsec, strongswan

I have a vps, and I tried to install a site-to-site vpn using stronswan and swanctl, I accidentally put remote_ts to 0.0.0.0/0 and now I can't access my vps through ssh.

How can I regain access ?

Comment: Use the OOB solution provided by your service provider. Most solutions have a OOB solution via e.g. VNC that allows you to interface the console.

Comment: Thank you, is there any other solution as I have no access to the OOB

Comment: No, not really, if you can't connect via the normal means you have to somehow bypass the network stack - and that means the console usually.

Comment: I tried to make a vpn connection from my local, but it gives me NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN when I am sure I put the same ike and esp proposals on both, can it be caused by the ip not the same as the one configured in the vps ?

Comment: Ok i will try to do that from console

Comment: @vidarlo I tried to access from upcloud console, but I didn't configure the server with password, just ssh keys. Now how can I solve this?